# MPI_Send/ Recv communicator datatype error

Tags: mpi, fortran90

I have the following basic MPI program written in Fortran 90:

```
program sendRecv
include 'mpif.h'

!MPI Variables
integer ierr, numProcs, procID
!My variables
integer dat, datRec

!Init MPI
call MPI_INIT ( ierr )
!Get number of processes/ cores requested
call MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, numProcs, ierr)
!Get rank of process
call MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, procID, ierr)

if (procID .eq. 0) then 
    dat=4

    !Send num to process 1
    call MPI_SEND (dat, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

else if (procID .eq. 1) then 
    !Recieve num from process 0
    call MPI_RECV (datRec, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_SIZE, ierr)

    !Display info   
    write(*,*) "Process 1 recieved ", datRec, " from proc 0"

else 
    write(*,*)"Into else"
end if

!Finilise MPI
call MPI_FINALIZE ( ierr )

end program sendRecv
```

The purpose is just to send an integer from process 0 and receive and display it in process 1, but whatever i seem to try, i cannot get it to work.

I am compiling and running this program with:

```
mpif90 sendRecv.f90 -o tst
mpirun -n 2 tst
```

and am getting this:

```
[conor-Latitude-XT2:3053] *** An error occurred in MPI_Send
[conor-Latitude-XT2:3053] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[conor-Latitude-XT2:3053] *** MPI_ERR_TYPE: invalid datatype
[conor-Latitude-XT2:3053] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (your MPI job will now abort)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 1 with PID 3054 on
node conor-Latitude-XT2 exiting without calling "finalize". This may
have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[conor-Latitude-XT2:03052] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[conor-Latitude-XT2:03052] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

I have looked around but i just cant spot my error. 
Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_INT` corresponds to the `int` type of C and C++. The Fortran `INTEGER` type is represented by the predefined MPI datatype `MPI_INTEGER`.

Besides there is another error in your code. You pass `MPI_STATUS_SIZE` whereas you have to pass an integer array of the same size, e.g.:

```
INTEGER status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

CALL MPI_SEND(..., status, ierr)
```

I would also recommend that you replace

```
include 'mpif.h'
```

with

```
use mpi
```

`mpif.h` is an obsoleted Fortran 77 interface and it should not be used in modern programs. The `mpi` module interface itself is also obsoleted by the `mpi_f08` module interface, but that comes from MPI-3.0 and is still not widely implemented.